# SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate throws Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, saxon, saxon-js

I am trying to use saxon JS to evaluate  some xPaths

I'm running the following code

```
const sourceCode= " ... " //a string representing the code source of https://www.imdb.com/chart/boxoffice

const doc = new DOMParser({errorHandler: () => {} }).parseFromString(sourceCode, 'text/html')

try {
        const res = saxon.XPath.evaluate(selectors[0].path, doc,  { xpathDefaultNamespace : 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' })
        console.log("saxon res", res);
} catch(e) {
        console.log("saxon e", e);
}
```

which throws the following error

```
saxon e RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at Hb.Cb (/application/node_modules/saxon-js/SaxonJS2N.js:3904:409)
at new Hb (/application/node_modules/saxon-js/SaxonJS2N.js:3905:286)
at Object.fromString (/application/node_modules/saxon-js/SaxonJS2N.js:3948:119)
at H (/application/node_modules/saxon-js/SaxonJS2N.js:4377:39)
at S (/application/node_modules/saxon-js/SaxonJS2N.js:4378:208)
at H (/application/node_modules/saxon-js/SaxonJS2N.js:4378:500)
at /application/node_modules/saxon-js/SaxonJS2N.js:4379:103
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at R (/application/node_modules/saxon-js/SaxonJS2N.js:4379:79)
at Y (/application/node_modules/saxon-js/SaxonJS2N.js:4379:196)
at H (/application/node_modules/saxon-js/SaxonJS2N.js:4379:28)

etc...
```

Same error for any webpage I have tried.
How can I parse a source code and evaluate the page with saxon-js

Note: I'm open to alternatives that use xpath 3.0
Note2: the code above works fine with npm xpath but it uses xpath 1

Comment: What is the XPath expression being evaluated? Please put together a repro and submit it at saxonica.plan.io. It could be a user error (it's possible to write XPath 3.1 expressions that are infinitely recursive) but if it's an expression that works in XPath 1.0 that seems unlikely.

Comment: You can use SaxonJS under Node.js to use XPath 3.1 but I think you are trying to run it against some DOM implementation it has not been built for/tested with (where does that DOMParser come from?), the predefined and tested way to parse input (might be only possible with X(HT)ML by default) would be to use https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/index.html#!api/getResource

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sorry, I forgot this important detail: DOMParser comes from xmldom.DOMParser from the xmldom npm package

Comment: I filed a feature request https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/5302 to suggest to look into integrating text/html parsing into the Node.js DOM implementation of Saxon-JS, I think so far it only handles application/xml parsing under Node.js for the DOM. No idea, however, whether it will be easy for them just to upgrade the `xmldom` integration to a more recent version or whether that needs some heavy lifting.

Answer (score 0):

In the browser Saxon-JS uses the browser's DOM implementation and interoperates fine with e.g. `new DOMParser().parseFromString('...', 'text/html')` but I think under Node.js integrates its own DOM based on "third-party components, including sax-js, xmldom, and Big", being "integrated into the saxon-js codebase".

I don't think they have integrated a text/html parser, so you can parse X(HT)ML using SaxonJS.getResource, but so far not HTML.

Example for XML:

```
const SaxonJS = require("saxon-js");

const htmlInput = `<html><body><h1>Test</h1>
<p>This is p 1.</p>
<p>This is p2.</p>
</body>
</html>`;

SaxonJS.getResource({ text : htmlInput, type : 'xml' }).then(doc => {

  const result = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`//p/string()`, doc);

  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: I ran the code above with the source code from https://www.imdb.com/chart/boxoffice and I get an error: 
message:Failed parsing XML in undefined: Invalid character in entity name at line 20 column 49', name: 'XError', code: 'FODC0002'
I assume that it works only with perfectly formatted XMLs, which is rarely the case of a web page. Isn't Saxon a tool that can be used for any xhtml page?

Comment: Saxon supports XPath, XSLT, these are primarily defined for XML input and with XPath 3.1 and XSLT 3.0 also for JSON input. HTML is a different input type/MIME type (text/html) which requires a different parser than an XML parser. So while I understand you want to run XPath against HTML or text/html, as far as I am aware, that is not supported with Saxon-JS under Node.js.

Comment: I can't tell what Saxon-JS does under the hood with xmldom under Node.js, whether it is easy for them to update to a version that supports parsing HTML (text/html). You will need to ask yourself or watch the issue https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/5302 I created, I think currently they are busy with fixing the obvious bugs in Saxon 11.1 under Java and C/C++/Python and perhaps .NET, hopefully we'll see more activity on Saxon-JS in the next weeks or months.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I will definitely follow the ticket